# Concrete First or Asphalt First

Tags: concrete, driveway, asphalt

We have a long asphalt common (5 residents share it) road, 25' wide x 550' long, that terminates at a City road. The asphalt is old (30+ years) and in bad repair, so we want to replace it and add concrete gutter and a concrete apron where the common road meets the City road. So the old asphalt needs to be removed, the road graded, and then replaced and in the process add the concrete apron/gutter. Is it common practice to construct the paved road first and then the concrete apron/gutter, or vice versa?

Comment: Judging by what's being done by the county widening a road near me, it's roadway base and initial asphalt, then concrete edging, then fill in the few inches gap between the 'base' asphalt & concrete, then final asphalt topping layer(s).

Comment: Asphalt last. Although it can be done first, then trimmed out where the concrete goes, then new asphalt packed in the gap.

Comment: both are doable. these days it's likely going to depend more on scheduling the delivery of material more than pros/cons of either. Ideally the gutters go in first (well really the storm drains go in first)...

Comment: Concrete first seems to line up with comments I have received from contractors as well, to avoid having to rework the asphalt to form the concrete.

Answer (score 3):

Not an expert (never done this myself, but seen it done), so if I turn out to be totally wrong I'll delete.

**Concrete first**

The asphalt will fill in edge to edge. With concrete apron and gutter first, that provides the edge (at least for some parts). With asphalt first, you would probably have to cut into it a bit and put in forms when pouring the concrete, and then backfill more asphalt after you are done.

Comment: I would have figure the other way if understanding right.  The concrete apron would be at the the roadway, and then would have heavy trucks driving over it for the asphalt.  Thought it might be better to do the concrete apron after.  This is if it roadway, then concrete apron/pad, then asphalt.